# How to initialize a built-in array in C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

I don't understand why we can assign values directly to `mi`. Usually, we use a format like `mi.a` but this turns out syntax error in this case. Could someone explain to me?

```
struct myInt {
  int a[7];
};
myInt mi;
mi= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an initializer, C++ allows recursive initialization of aggregates, that is you don't need a second set of { } in the initializer if it can't be ambigious (as it can not here as there are no other memebrs to initialize).